# Configure log4j

Tags: java, log4j

I am trying to use `org.apache.log4j.Logger` in my project. I have **dowloaded log4j-1.2.17**, and **added the jar package to my referenced packages** in Eclipse. And I **create a file** at the root of my project(which I think is the current directory denoted by '.' in CLASSPATH) as the configuration file. The content is as follows:

```
log4j.rootLogger=info, stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
# Pattern to output the caller's file name and line number.
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%5p [%t] (%F:%L) - %m%n
```

In my project:

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;


public class Recommend {    

    private final static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(Recommend.class);
    //...
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        log.info("Hello world!");
    }
```

But it won't print the message in the console, and yield an warning instead saying:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (main.Recommend).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

How can I make it work? Thanks for your attention!

Comment: try to set logj4 properties file in src folder

Comment: @AlekseiBulgak yeah, finally..it works. So this means the current directory is the src directory instead of the root of the project. Is it correct?

Comment: @AlekseiBulgak But that doesn't make sense, for that when I write files in my code using relative path, the current directory IS the root direcotry...

Comment: I don't sure exactly. But I have the same problem as yours and only putting log4j.properties file in src folder fix it.

Comment: I think root directory depends on project. If you make simple desktop project root directory is your sec folder. and if you create web app in this dituation your root directory is WebContent(folder that contains WEB-INF folder)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the log4j.properties file is in the classpath.

Answer (score 1):

> your log4j.properties file in src folder its work great.replace of log4j.xml just put your log4j.properties file

[image]